# What is Minahan-Nemeschansky’s theory?

Tags: string-theory, field-theory, supersymmetry

Page 190 of *${\cal N}=2$ Supersymmetric Dynamics for Pedestrians* Yuji Tachikawa book is saying;

> "Generalizing this to the E8 symmetry is by now rather straightforward. We perform
> the duality as shown in Fig. 12.23.
> In the dual side, we have a three-punctured sphere
> with one full puncture, another of type .2; 2; 2/, and of type .3; 3/. We see that the
> flavor symmetry F of the theory should satisfy
> LIE groups conmutative.
> This nicely fits the structure of Minahan–Nemeschansky’s theory MN.E8/, see
> Fig. 12.24. Checks of various properties are left as an exercise to the reader."

What is [Minahan-Nemeschansky](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=minahan+nemeschansky)’s theory?